# swagger encoding URL

Tags: node.js, swagger, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have an API is nodejs and I'm using swagger to test it.

It works for all gets, posts, puts and deletes. However I'm trying to add a new get, passing a query as parameter. I define param type as 'any'. It works on insomnia, but in swagger the query passed as parameter is getting encoded and then the return is not the correct filter.

I can see the request URL field on swagger is showing an incorrect URL, using many symbols (encoded).

I think it might have something to do with swagger using x-www-form-urlencoded, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where is your [mcve]?

Comment: Please post the code of your GET method, and a screenshot of request data sent from Swagger UI.